# How to write this ticket in esc commands?

Tags: android, escpos

I am able to write cpcl commands and it works fine(The ticket printed is beautiful). But now I have another printer (sunmi v2s plus) that does not support cpcl commands.

So could anybody help me to write same things but in esc/pos commands?

[image]

Comment: It seems that the document is distributed on this page, so please get what you need and check it out. [Printing Service](https://docs.sunmi.com/en/general-function-modules/printing-service/print-and-customer-display/)

Comment: Thank you so much, but i have already seen this document. This document says that we can use the api to send data and print, or directly use esc commands and send them . The first option rely too much on the network. But thank you anyway

Comment: Perhaps the price of large and beautiful letters is printed as an image. The title string can be either a printer font or an image. The ESC/POS commands necessary for printing them are those described in this document described on the page commented above. [ESCPOSinstruction documentation](https://ota.cdn.sunmi.com/DOC/resource/re_en/ESC-POS%20Command%20set.docx)

Comment: I think this maybe is a disadvantage of esc commands, because the ticket i posted is write in cpcl commands, so im thinking maybe cpcl could be translate to esc commands??

Comment: In addition, printing characters in the same line range on the left and right of the barcode with printer fonts requires ESC/POS to support page mode, but the command for that is not described in the specification. If the distributed ESC/POS specifications are incomplete, you can get the correct specifications, but if the current specifications are correct, to satisfy what you want to print using ESC/POS commands, you need to create and print everything as an image.

Comment: I think you are right , i must at first create all in image and then print them